# How to convert PDF to JPG with PDFTron

Tags: android, pdftron

My goal is to convert my fillable pdf document to an image and then save it to my database on Kumulos. I'm having issues converting the pdf document with PDFTron. The error that I am getting is that the file does not exist. However, I am able to pull the file and view it in the app.

```
switch (Global.g){
        case 1:
            InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.incident_report);
            try{
                doc = new PDFDoc(is);
            }catch (PDFNetException e){
                doc = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch (IOException e){
                doc = null;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                mPDFViewCtrl.setDoc(doc);
                save_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try{
                            String output_path = "../../raw/Output/";

                            PDFDraw draw=new PDFDraw();  // PDFDraw class is used to rasterize PDF pages.
                            ObjSet hint_set=new ObjSet();

                            PDFDoc doc=new PDFDoc((mPDFViewCtrl + "incident_report.pdf"));
                            // Initialize the security handler, in case the PDF is encrypted.
                            doc.initSecurityHandler();

                            draw.setDPI(72); // Set the output resolution is to 72 DPI.

                            // Use optional encoder parameter to specify JPEG quality.
                            Obj encoder_param=hint_set.createDict();
                            encoder_param.putNumber("Quality", 80);

                            // Traverse all pages in the document.
                            for (PageIterator itr=doc.getPageIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                                Page current=(Page)(itr.next());
                                String filename=output_path+"incident_report"+current.getIndex() + ".jpg";
                                System.out.println(filename);
                                draw.export(current, filename, "JPEG", encoder_param);
                            }

                            doc.close();

                        }catch(PDFNetException e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                cancel_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });
            } catch (PDFNetException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line looks incorrect.

```
PDFDoc doc=new PDFDoc((mPDFViewCtrl + "incident_report.pdf"));
```

It should just be

```
PDFDoc doc=mPDFViewCtrl.getDoc();
```

That should solve your unable to read error.

Looking at your code though there are a number of other issues.

1. You don't call initSecurityHandler on the first PDFDoc object
2. You should acquire a read lock, since you are accessing the document outside of the PDFViewCtrl class (which doesn't know you are doing this). In this particular case you could probably get by without, since you are not modifying the document, but it best to get the read lock.

Here is the corrected code

```
InputStream is = res.openRawResource(R.raw.incident_report);
try{
    doc = new PDFDoc(is);
    doc.initSecurityHandler(); // handle passwordless but encrypted files
}catch (PDFNetException e){
    doc = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}catch (IOException e){
    doc = null;
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    mPDFViewCtrl.setDoc(doc);
    save_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                String output_path = "../../raw/Output/";
                PDFDraw draw=new PDFDraw();
                draw.setDPI(72);
                ObjSet hint_set=new ObjSet();
                Obj encoder_param=hint_set.createDict();
                encoder_param.putNumber("Quality", 80);

                // Get PDF being viewed and get read lock
                PDFDoc doc=mPDFViewCtrl.getDoc();
                mPDFViewCtrl.docLockRead();

                for (PageIterator itr=doc.getPageIterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
                    Page current=(Page)(itr.next());
                    String filename=output_path+"incident_report"+current.getIndex() + ".jpg";
                    System.out.println(filename);
                    draw.export(current, filename, "JPEG", encoder_param);
                }
            }catch(PDFNetException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                mPDFViewCtrl.docUnlockRead(); // release read lock
            }
            finish();
        }
    });

    cancel_Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
        }
    });
} catch (PDFNetException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: hmm still getting an error. I think its my output_path                                I/System.out: ../../raw/Output/incident_report1.jpg
intelwatch W/System.err: Exception: 
intelwatch W/System.err: Message: No such file or directory
intelwatch W/System.err: Conditional expression: m_stream != NULL

Comment: If you think PDFDraw.export is having problems accessing a folder on the device, then you could use PDFDraw.getBitmap(Page) which returns an android.graphics.Bitmap object. Then you can use that to write to disk as you like. If this works, but the same path in PDFDraw.export does not, please file a ticket with PDFTron support.